# How do we find an analytic function F, such that F' = f, when the function is given in terms of z, and not x and y directly?

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that if given a complex valued function, we can find an analytic function $F$, such that $F' = f$ using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. However, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are given in terms of the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, and so when I have a complex valued function in terms of $z$, like $f(z) = \sin(z)\cos(z)$ for example, letting $z = x + iy$ makes the problem significantly more complicated to solve. So, I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way to find the function using the Cauchy-Riemann equations without letting $z = x + iy$.

As another example, consider the function $$f(z) = \frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2}.$$

Comment: The ordinary rules of differentiation of rational functions apply to $f(z)$.  So you don't have to appeal to the Cauchy-Riemann equations unless you insist on working with the real variables $x,y$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$ f(z) = z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}
$$
This can be integrated the same way as real variate functions, so
$$ F(z) = \frac{z^3}{3} - \frac{1}{z}
$$
The point is to find $F$ that satisfies $F' = f$, and it turns out that integrating as if it is real works.

Comment: (wait for it). ... plus $C$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected region $\Omega$. To find $F\in H(\Omega)$ such that $F'=f$, fix $a\in \Omega$ and define $F:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$
F(z) = \int_\gamma f(\xi)d\xi,
$$
where $\gamma$ is a path in $\Omega$ with endpoints $a$ and $z$.